# C - exit for loop by pressing enter key

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I'm trying to print a string of chars from an array and end the loop whenever I press the "Enter" key.

```
int i;
char charArry[MAXARY];

printf("Input an array of chars: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < MAXARY && charArry[i] != 13; i++)
{
    scanf(" %c", &charArry[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < MAXARY; i++)
{
    printf(" %c", charArry[i]);
}
```

For some reason whenever I press the Enter key it just goes to a new line instead of breaking the loop. Any suggestions?

P.S
MAXARY is a constant for the array length, currently 20.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: You're only reading uninitialized values of `charArry`

Comment: `charArry[i]` will never be 13 (`'\r'`) given `" %c"`.  Could use `"%c"`, but that make cause other issues.  Usually the "enter" is translates into `'\n'`, but same problem.

Comment: Still going to UV this one as OP _attempted_ to do an important code test: prevent overflow with `i < MAXARY`.

Comment: @melpomene - That's for a friend's school work, he got to use scanf

Comment: @DaniRashba Why are you doing your friend's homework?

Comment: @melpomene Because I'm interested in programming, and although I have some VERY basic knowledge in C# and JS. I'm interested in tackling C and the way I learn is by putting myself in these kinds of situations. Learning the syntax is easy, becoming a good programmer, at least the way I see it, makes you need to spit blood while debugging code.

Comment: @DaniRashba Well, then start by reading the documentation for `scanf`. It's doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: debug. for example, add a printf ("%d\n"  right after your scanf in the first loop and see what values you are actually getting....

Comment: regarding this line: `for (i = 0; i < MAXARY && charArry[i] != 13; i++)`  it is checking each byte of the `charArry[]`, one char in each iteration of the `for()` loop, BUT 1) the char being checked has not been set via the call to `scanf()` until after the check.  2) this means checking values that have not been initialized.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf(" %c", &charArry[i]);`  the leading space in the format specifier string causes all 'white space' to be consumed.  The '13' is a 'white space' character.   NOTE; depending on the OS, the first character of a newline might not be 13.  Suggest using '\n' which the OS will handle appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close to having this working. Whilst I agree the use of `scanf` should be avoided, see: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), the reason your program doesn't do what you expect is due to a logic error.

Your for loop states:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXARY && charArry[i] != 13; i++)
```

Now recapping how a for loop works, you have:

```
1. initalization (i=0)
2. conditional check (i < MAXARY && charArry[i] != 13)
3.        conditional block (scanf)
4. increment (i++)
5. return to 2
```

You'll note your `charArray[i] != 13`check is happening after `i` has been incremented. Hence your not checking against the character you just read but the next character in charArray[i]. This is why your never breaking your loop at the `\r` character.

A recommended fix would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXARY; i++)
{
    int result = scanf("%c", &charArry[i]);
    if( result != 1 || charArry[i] == '\n' )
       break;
}
```

Which checks scanf was successful and charArry when `i` is the character that was read.

Also note as [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) has pointed out the `\r` character is a carrage return, not the newline. Hence this check will only work if your working on windows (as unix doesn't use `\r`). If you want to be platform independant use `\n`

Comment: Oops, yes agreed, meant to remove that.

Comment: Note that in text mode, Windows filters out the `\r` where the textfile's end of line is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

> For some reason whenever I press the Enter key it just goes to a new line instead of breaking the loop.

The space in the format `scanf(" %c", &charArry[i]);` directs `scanf()` to consume and discard all optional leading white-space.  `charArry[i]` will never be assigned `13` as 13 is typically `'\r'`, a white-space.

---

An enter key is usually translated to `'\n'`.

Do not test values that have not been assigned [@Red Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110083/c-exit-for-loop-by-pressing-enter-key#comment69424664_41110083)

```
//                        v---------v not assigned yet.       
for (i = 0; i < MAXARY && charArry[i] != 13
```

Repaired code

```
int i;
char charArry[MAXARY];

printf("Input an array of chars: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < MAXARY; i++) {
  if (scanf("%c", &charArry[i]) != 1) break;  // End of file or error occurred
  // If enter key encountered
  // Usualy the charArry[i] == '\r' is not needed.
  if (charArry[i] == '\n' ||  charArry[i] == '\r') break;
}

// Only print out characters that were read.
int j;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%c", charArry[j]);
}
```